# Maven using the same artifact with different name

Tags: maven

I have a problem using maven, I use a SNAPSHOT version from a internal component on my ear project and I have the follow problem:

So, I declare my poms likelike this:

main pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>mycomponent</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

ejb project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mycomponent</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

web project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mycomponent</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

So after clean install my ear is generate like this:

```
myear.ear
    | -- lib
    |       |--mycomponent-1.0.0-20160601.124237-1.jar  
    |--myejb.jar
    |--mywar.war
            |-META-INF
            |       | -MANIFEST.MF //my classpath has the value lib/mycomponent-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
            |-WEB-INF
                |-- lib
                    |-mycomponent-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

So, why maven using the same artifact with different names? How can I force maven to use only SNAPSHOT name, not the unique name? I try useUniqueVersions = false, but I don't have any success.

Comment: Can you show your pom files which you are using?

Comment: It looks like you have defined the dependency as a dependency of the EAR project. But without the pom files it's impossible to say what's wrong...